# Solve congruence equation using primitive roots and indices

Tags: number-theory

I am having trouble solving the equation $ x^7 \equiv 3 \; \pmod  9 $ using primitive roots and theory of indices. Can someone please help? I got $ 2 $ and $ 5 $ are primitive roots of $ 9 $ by finding primitive roots of $ 3 $ and so $ x^7 \equiv 3 \; \pmod  9 $ means $ x^7 - 2 \equiv 1 \; \pmod  9. $ Hence $ x^7 - 2 \equiv 2^6 \; \pmod  9 $ or $ x^7 - 2 \equiv 5^6 \; \pmod  9, $ but this approach doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

$x^7 \equiv 3 \bmod 9$ implies $x^7 \equiv 0 \bmod 3$ and so $x \equiv 0 \bmod 3$. But then $x^7 \equiv 0 \bmod 9$ and so $x^7 \equiv 3 \bmod 9$ has no solution.

Comment: @newbie, $x^7=3+9a=3(1+3a)$.